# Using @contextmanager and yield in order to wait for a page to load

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, contextmanager

I am using the following code based on this [blogpost](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html) (last section):

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import staleness_of
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

@contextmanager
def wait_for_page_load(self, timeout=15):
    old_page = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
    yield
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(staleness_of(old_page))
```

where `self.driver` is a selenium webdriver object.
This context manager can then be used in a `with` block:

```py
def click_on_the_link():
    with self.wait_for_page_load():
        self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('a link')
```

The way I understood it is that the old page is stored and in case the new page hasn't loaded yet it, a WebDriverWait object is created, which waits for the site to be loaded before continuing. Then the actions on the new page are executed, e.g. clicking a link.

However, the code doesn't make sense to me. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html):

> At the point where the generator yields, the block nested in the with statement is executed. The generator is then resumed after the block is exited.

Assuming the code in the blogpost is correct, how can the method possibly wait for the site to be loaded if the code inside the `with` statement is executed first?

Answer (score -1):

Because it uses an [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(staleness_of(old_page))
```

This will wait until the contition `staleness_of` succeeds or throws an exception if the timeout is reached. Since this code is executed after the `yield`, any operation with the driver will be caught by this.

**UPDATE**

If you just want your driver to wait for the element `a link` you can use `WebDriverWait` directly

```py
def click_on_the_link(self):
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
    wait.until(element_to_be_clickable('a link'))
    self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('a link')
```

Comment: Then what could I change to achieve what I want?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Didn't you wanted to know how the decorator worked?

Comment: Yes exactly, but maybe this didn't become clear in my question. The given code doesn't do what it should do because I only want the code in `click_on_the_link` to be executed after loading. So I want to know a way to achieve this

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have used your suggested method before, however it has some flaws which is why I searched for an alternative way. With `wait.until()` there is no way to stop waiting before the maximum time is reached. I need a way to exit if a certain element on the site cannot be found. But I can only check this condition once the site has fully loaded.